# Listing \lstset add character instead of space

Tags: listings

I'm seeing a " character, where there should be a space or tab, with the listings package. See example below.
[image]

That code would be:

```
buffer:     .space 151
.text
.globl main
main:
addi    $sp, $sp, -28
sw  $s0, 0($sp)
sw  $s1, 4($sp)
sw  $s2, 8($sp)
sw  $s3, 12($sp)
sw  $s4, 16($sp)
sw  $s5, 20($sp)
sw  $s6, 24($sp)

la  $s0, buffer         # File letto
add $s1, $zero, $zero       # Offset
move    $s2, $zero          # Cont
```

Latex code:

```
\lstset{
 language=[mips]Assembler,
 basicstyle=\fontfamily{lmss}\footnotesize,
 numbers=left,                  
 numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
 stepnumber=1,
 numbersep=5pt,
 backgroundcolor=\color{white},
 showspaces=false, 
 showstringspaces=false,
 showtabs=false,
 frame=single,
 rulecolor=\color{black},
 tabsize=3,
 captionpos=b,
 breaklines=true,
 breakatwhitespace=true,
 keywordstyle=\color{blue},
 commentstyle=\color{dkgreen}, 
 stringstyle=\color{mauve},
 escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
Any solution to solve?

Comment: Using `mips.sty` from https://gist.github.com/walkie/4591789 I see no problem.  Are you using the same style file?  Or perhaps there is a character encoding issue.

Comment: Yes, it's the same file. 
But the output it's like in pic, I can't undestand why.

Comment: I think instead of using 
`\lstinputlisting{*name file*}`
I will copy and paste directly the code inside the document. Very uncomfortable but it works

Comment: It works for me inputting the code from a separate file, just make sure the character encoding is correct.

Comment: The file it's `assembler source, UTF-8 Unicode text` is it the correct encode type?

Comment: If it is `utf-8` then you will need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your LaTeX document.  By default LaTeX expects to read an ASCII type encoding.

Comment: Yes, but the problem it's still there.. The strange character do not disappear.

Comment: Hmm... I can't reproduce the problem.  Are you sure there are no "hidden" characters in the code file?

Comment: What do you mean with "hidden" characters?

Comment: I have seen document that turned out to contained utf-8 characters that were not directly visible, being rendered as narrow/zero width spaces.  I am acutually surprised your assembly code is utf-8 - I would expect ascii